# How to get most recent order date?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing an external exercise where I have a set of data of customers' purchases.

I have the following columns: `customer_id`,  `date`, `gender`, `value` (purchase value). One part of the exercise is to create a new column named `most_recent_order_date`. How should I go about accomplishing this?

I tried

```
df['most_recent_order_date']=df.sort_values('customer_id',ascending=False)['date']
```

but this only returns the dates of all purchases in ascending order. I need it to be `customer_id` specific since a `customer_id` might have multiple purchases.

Another part of the exercise is to create a `order_count` column which is what the last column is.

```
data= pd.read_csv('screening_exercise_orders_v201810.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['most_recent_order_date']= 'default value'
df['order_count']= 'default value'

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['most_recent_order_date']=df.sort_values('customer_id',ascending=False)['date']
df['order_count']= df.groupby(['customer_id']).transform('count')
df.head(10)
```

I expect something like:

```
0   1000    0   2017-01-01 00:11:31 198.50  1   2017-02-10 00:11:   1
1   1001    0   2017-01-01 00:29:56 338.00  1   2017-11-01 00:29:56 1
2   1002    1   2017-01-01 01:30:31 733.00  1   2017-06-11 01:30:31 3
3   1003    1   2017-01-01 01:34:22 772.00  1   2017-05-14 01:34:22 4
4   1004    0   2017-01-01 03:11:54 508.00  1   2017-01-01 03:11:54 1
```

But what I actually get is:

```
0   1000    0   2017-01-01 00:11:31 198.50  1   2017-01-01 00:11:31 1
1   1001    0   2017-01-01 00:29:56 338.00  1   2017-01-01 00:29:56 1
2   1002    1   2017-01-01 01:30:31 733.00  1   2017-01-01 01:30:31 3
3   1003    1   2017-01-01 01:34:22 772.00  1   2017-01-01 01:34:22 4
4   1004    0   2017-01-01 03:11:54 508.00  1   2017-01-01 03:11:54 1
```

Comment: Try `df.groupby(['customer_id'])['date'].transform('max')`

Comment: Wow Thank you very  much!! I have been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most recent date, use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `max`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['most_recent_date'] = df.groupby(['customer_id'])['date'].transform('max')
```

For count use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['order_count'] = df.groupby(['customer_id']).cumcount().add(1)
```